# How to find τ in these circuits?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, resistors, resistance

1. [image: circuit 1]
2. [image: circuit 2]

I know that \$τ = \frac{L}{R}\$, but what is \$R\$ in this formula? It seems to be the total resistance, but how to find it in the schematics?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried yourself yet?

Comment: It's not a homework, I just don't know what is R in this formula :/.

Comment: Where did you find these circuits. And _again_, what have you tried yourself yet?

Comment: Solve R (and U) by using Thévenin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrows on the switches seem to indicate they are opening. I assume (but your problem statement should be more clear about this) that this means the switches are closed for t < 0 and open for t > 0, and you want to solve for the indicated voltages as a function of time for t > 0.

For the 1st one, once you open the switch, there's only one resistor in the circuit, so R is given by its resistance.

For the 2nd one, after the switch opens, there's no current through the 4 kOhm resistor, so you can ignore it. What's the equivalent resistance of the remaining two resistors?

Comment: ok, so when I want to find the total resistance, I find it after I open the switch, right? Should I change the voltage source and the inductor into a wire? What if there were a current source and a conductor instead?
Thank you very much :). Accepted:)

Comment: To find the steady state condition (the limit as t -> infinity) you consider the inductor as a wire. But an ideal inductor's current can't change instantaneously, so at t = 0+ you can see it as a current source (meaning infinite resistance).

Comment: thank you :). If there were conductor instead of a inductor - should I treat it as a wire as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *conductor* instead of inductor. If it's a wire, treat it as a wire. If it's a resistor with a specification in siemens (conductance units) treat it as a resistor.

Comment: oh, sorry. I mean a capacitor - what if we put a capacitor instead of the inductor? Sould I treat it as a wire, too?

Comment: A capacitor is complementary to the inductor. The capacitor voltage can't change instantaneously so at t=0+ it behaves something like a voltage source; but as t -> infinity it becomes an open circuit.

Comment: ok, so when I want to find R to τ formula, should I consider the circuit right after the key opening (t0)? or in t->infinity?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i think

- In the First case:

Solve Short the inductor and solve both resistances in parallel

- In the second case:

Short the inductor again, Solve two 1k resistances in series and then solve again in series this equivalent resistance with 4k. 
you will get your overall equivalent resistances in both cases.

Comment: thank you! Accepted :).
Should I short the voltage source as well? What if there were a current source?
and btw. what if we put a conductor instead of the inductor? Sould I short it, too?

Comment: Notice the arrows show the switches are going open (at t=0) not closed. This means the circuits are much simpler during the time we want to know the time constant.

Comment: Your answer for the second case is wrong. The equvalent resistance for the purpose of the time constant is the two 1k resistor in series, then that in *parallel* with the 4k resistor. The result is 1.33 kOhms, not 6 kOhms as your method yields.  That is for the switch closed case.  In the switch open case it is simply 2 kOhms.